# How to store the database value in array?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

im new to codeignitor and suffering to store a database value in array and pass it through other page

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
    echo $row->name;
    echo $row->body;
}
```

instead of echo it should be stored in array and pass it to other page as a argument.. is it possible??

Comment: You need to read through the tutorials. There are numerous tutorials for codeigniter. try this link : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Answer (score 3):

This code return the query result as array, now you can use the array inside your controller and pass it to your view.

```
$data = array();

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $data[] = array(
        'title' => $row->title,
        'name'  => $row->name,
        'body'  => $row->body
    );
}

return $data;
```